Webix: Using inner datalayout in Datalayout's Repeater Mode
I'm trying to diplay grouped list using Datalayout.
Data structure looks like:

Date 1



List item 1




List item 2


Date 2



List item 1




List item 2



I've found that Repeater mode of Datalayout is what I'm looking for. It works perfectly with view: "list" and other similar  components, but I need some more complex solution, to apply some styles and responsiveness, so I don't want to use plain HTML here.
Inner datalayout fits perfectly here, but it doesn't work... All inner properties are 'underfined'. Looks like it cannot process inner datalayouts. Am I right?
Sample: https://snippet.webix.com/rbl1yzj2

It can process inner datalayouts, https://snippet.webix.com/37m0t11a it's not an object that is in template, it's the value from name-d field.
